# Is it possible to write a windowed unbounded PCollection to a specific BQ partition?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

Given a Windowed PCollection in streaming, I would like to write to a specific partition in a BQ table based on the window.

When specifying a `tableSpecFunction` for `BigQueryIO.Write.Bound.to(SerializableFunction<BoundedWindow,String> tableSpecFunction)` [(docs)](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/BigQueryIO.Write.html#to-com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.SerializableFunction) it seems I am only able to specify an alphanumeric name for the table reference string.

With no table decorator specified, it seems the data is written to a partition ID of `__UNPARTITIONED__`. AFAICT this will eventually resolve to [today's partition](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/BigQueryIO.Write.html#to-com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.SerializableFunction).

For my use case, I would like the data to be immediately accessible in the correct partition. Additionally it would also be great to be able to account for late data and write that to the correct partition as well.

So to restate my question:

Is it possible to write a windowed unbounded PCollection to a specific BQ partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the partition name directly. BigQuery APIs (streaming) supports writing to a given partition of the table by using a partition decorator for a table. For example, to write to partition for 2016-05-01 for table T, you'd use  T$20160501

Does the `<table_name>$<date>` syntax not work for you?

Comment: Whoops.

I was thrown because on one of my test runs I was seeing this in the logs: 

"Table IDs must be alphanumeric (plus underscores) and must be at most 1024 characters long. Also, Table decorators cannot be used"

However it seems I didn't properly clear my test dataset so I must have been trying address a partition in a non-partition table. 

I just tried again on a clean dataset and it worked.

PEBKAC